# How to automate select2 search boxes using robot framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm trying to select values from select2 search box. However selecting values from hidden drop-down didn't work from me using robot selenium2Library keywords.

Is there any particular way to deal with select2 boxes? Anybody tried out the same.

You can refer Example section at  http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ to get an idea of select2 search box. I'm trying to automate the same kind of search box using robot.

Any help world be really appreciated.

-Krishantha Samaraweera

Comment: What did you try? In what way did it not work? For me `Select From List    e1    Nevada` does select Nevada from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select From List By Label source  Alaska` it works fine!